# How to use Category Heading instead of Category name in Magento?

Tags: category, category-attribute

There is a field in the backend called "Category Heading" that I would like to use instead of "Category Name" under View. Current code is like

```
<h1 class="cate"><?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_category->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
```

Please guide me how to fetch it. Also, is there simple documentation for all this stuff?

Comment: You can always dump to see what's available. `var_dump($_category)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to the category title, you can get it like this:

```
echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_category->getMetaTitle(), 'meta_title');
```

If there is a custom field category header, do like this:

```
Mage::log(print_r($_category->debug(), true), null, 'category.log', true);
```

and then go to `var/log/category.log` and you will find there all the info you need.